# Conditional sentences punctuation: Comma before "if" if there is an "or" before it?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conditionals

Should there be a comma before "if" on this sentence?

> Stop by and introduce yourself or, if you’ve already had a 
>   chance to meet him, swing by to get to know him a little better!

Comment: The presence or otherwise of the comma doesn't worry me, but I'd like a dash after 'yourself'.

Comment: A comma in the same location would suffice, but one or other is necessary with the use of or before an independent clause ('swing by....'). And yeah, the commas around "if...him" are necessary.

Answer (score -2):

The comma should go before "or".  The standard you are looking for is 'commas with coordinating conjunctions with independent clauses.